# Why are my Knockout Radio buttons failing when inside another element with a click binding?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a list of radio buttons. I want clicks on the `<li>` their in to also check the radio button. This all works up until I put a `name` attribute on the radio elements. Then my code stops working.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: rows">
    <li data-bind="click: function() { $parent.val($data); }">
        <input type="radio" name="my_radio" data-bind="value: $data, checked: $parent.val" />
        <label data-bind="text: $data"></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here are two test cases.

*Be sure to click on both the radio button and row.*

**Working:** http://jsfiddle.net/Dihedral/HJGxX/2/

**Not Working:** http://jsfiddle.net/Dihedral/HJGxX/3/

In the second case and when clicking on just the radio, you'll see that the val() observable is being updated, but the UI is not. Anyone know what's going on here, or can see a workaround?

Comment: +1, unexpected behavior indeed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The click is not reaching the radio button because knockoutjs returns false from the click handler, preventing the default action to happen (see: [note 3](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)). Just return true from the click handler (http://jsfiddle.net/HJGxX/4/):

```
<li data-bind="click: function() { $parent.val($data); return true; }">
```

Comment: Whoa! That's a great fix. Thanks! It seems like there is still a bug with Knockout? I would have expected Knockout to update the UI for me once the observable changed.

Answer (score 0):

Having the name attributes all set to the same value makes all these radio buttons part of the same set, and you can only select one of them at once.

Read more about on radio buttons name attribute on [www.W3.org](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_forms_-_the_basics#Radio_buttons%3a_a_multiple_choice_option)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the behavior I'm looking for. However I am unable to select a different radio button at this time.

Comment: I think the OP got that, but the problem is that if you click on an actual circle in the second example, the click's registered (i.e. the View Model updates) but the UI won't select the newly clicked radio. No-one's expecting two boxes to be selected at any time.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense now. The fix from mhu worked. However I'm surprised Knockout didn't handle the UI update for me.