# Knockout: Unable to bind to a button's click event when using Bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am having trouble with Knockout executing Javascript when a user clicks on a button. Unfortunately this is quite a complex page, and I cannot show the full content, but hopefully the small snippet below is enough.

I have tried to simplify this by not even calling the actual view model in the Knockout binding of `data-bind`, and instead I just simply alert.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: MyComputedStuff()">
...
  <div class="popover-content">
    <button onclick="alert('bar')">
      This works!
    </button>
    <button data-bind="click: function(data, event){alert('foo')}">
      THIS DOES NOT WORK
    </button>
  </div>
...
</div>
```

Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong here?

Why is it impossible for `alert('foo')` to be executed?

**It might help to know that we use Bootstrap and this particular button is within a [popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) div.**

**Edit:**

I see nothing in the console, and the rest of the page's Javascript continues to work as normal. I have tried this in Chrome and IE9.

I should have said that I am able to bind the click event on another element within the same `foreach`, to a function in the view model. This works, and this is what I expected to be able to duplicate. (If I replace the call to a function with `alert('blah')` then I see alert as expected here.) So why not on my button??

```
<a rel="tooltip" 
  title="Favourite App"
  data-bind="click: function(data, event){$root.ToggleFavorite(data)}">
```

Comment: What's happening when you click? any error? did you check console for errors?

Comment: @haim770 Nothing in the console, and the rest of the page's JS continues to function. Tried in Chrome and IE9.

Comment: Usually when you do a clickbinding, the method itself is declared in the ViewModel like this http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html.  Could be that KO is not set up to deal with functions in the way you've done it?

Comment: Did you call `applyBindings()`?

Comment: @haim770 Yes, as other bindings are working.

Comment: @AlexanderTroup KO is able to bind the click event to other elements, although I am yet to bind to a button element.

Comment: in your second example, you're calling $root.ToggleFavourite(), whereas in your first you're trying to declare the function within your data-bind.  I Imagine that ToggleFavourite refers to a method declared in the viewModel.  see what I mean?

Comment: If I replace `$root.ToggleFavorite(data)` with `alert('abc')` then I will see the alert. This makes me think that the problem is not with my view model at all, but with KO binding.

Comment: Starting to think you omitted something essential in your code snippet up there, i.e. the part that breaks the expected behaviour. Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/Yrj85/1/ it works fine there!

Comment: Seems to be an issue with `ko.computed`, see http://jsfiddle.net/Yrj85/2/ (computed) vs http://jsfiddle.net/Yrj85/1/ (simple observable array)

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake in http://jsfiddle.net/Yrj85/2/ (omitted a closing bracket, SILENT error). This broke the behaviour, it works just fine in http://jsfiddle.net/Yrj85/5/. Could it be that you made the same mistake by chance?

Comment: @UweB I do not think I have made the same mistake as I am seeing all the elements (9+) of the array printed out.

Comment: Do you have a (on)click handler on a parent object of the button? Could it be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18521600/932282

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you to haim770, Alexander, UweB and mhu for your help.**

A colleague has pointed out the reason for Knockout not binding the click event: **Bootstrap was modifying the DOM.**

Through the use of the [Knockout context debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en) Chrome extention, my colleague pointed out that the div element that contained my buttons was not within an area where I had told Knockout to apply bindings to ... Bootstrap had moved it.

I was using the [popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) feature of Bootstrap, and my button was within a *popover* that Bootstrap had moved out of the div that I was `foreach`ing.